# Nomenclature for reflexive and symmetric relations

Tags: terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

What is the common name for binary relations that are *reflexive* and *symmetric* (but not necessarily transitive)?

In other words: What is the *generalization of an equivalence relation* where *transitivity* is dropped commonly called?

I found [tolerance relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_relation) but these seem to carry yet more structure / occur in a more specific context.

Update: I also stumbled across *similarity relation* somewhere.

Comment: I don't believe there is a universally accepted name for such.  If you found one that some people accepted, you'd still have to (re)define it for the benefit of everyone else.

Comment: Agreed. But I'd still like to know if there are names that have been used (somewhat often) before.

Comment: Tolerance relation is a good name for it. Notice that there are algebras in which every equivalence relation is a congruence, because compatibility hods trivially. For example, left, or right-zero semigroups, null semigroups (where the operation is constant), and surely others I can't remember now. In these, every reflexive and symmetric relation is a tolerance. Actually, from the very first paragraph of the linked article: "On a set, an algebraic structure with empty family of operations, tolerance relations are simply reflexive symmetric relations."